# Mtree addon blender 2.83.10: Leaves and Tree branches separated in Particle System

Tags: particles

I have an addon Mtree which I make trees and leaves the addon itself is working fine. The problem is, when I want to scatter the tree with particle system I only get the trunk and not the leaves, I tried to join the tree and the leaves but got the same result, I also tried a collection but to no avail. Can someone give me a solution?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a real solution but it works. Select the tree and the leaves Export selected as .FBX then import again then join. Just like that you can just move it around and scatter it together.

Comment: Exporting and re importing is rarely the solution, it will lead to data loss like materials and modifiers

Comment: ill give it a try thanks